# Copy/Clone table records using jQuery MVC5

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, clone

I am working on Salon booking system using **MVC5**, what I want to do is:
 after the admin enters the working hours for each employee "in BookedHours table" for the current week; there should be a button that repeats the same records for the next week (just change the **DATE** field).

Can I do that using **jQuery** in the View

Thanks

the Index view:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<BookingSystem.Models.WorkingHour>
:
:
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>

        @Html.ActionLink("Branch", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.BranchSortParm, currentFilter1 = ViewBag.CurrentFilter1, currentFilter2 = ViewBag.CurrentFilter2 })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter1 = ViewBag.CurrentFilter1, currentFilter2 = ViewBag.CurrentFilter2 })
    </th>
    <th>
       @Html.ActionLink("Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm, currentFilter1 = ViewBag.CurrentFilter1, currentFilter2 = ViewBag.CurrentFilter2 })
    </th>
    <th>
        Day
    </th>
    <th>
        Start Time
    </th>
    <th>
        End Time
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Branch.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceProvider.FullName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Date.DayOfWeek
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.WorkingHourID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.WorkingHourID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.WorkingHourID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The Create view:

```
    @model BookingSystem.Models.WorkingHour

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>WorkingHour</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Select Shift", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Direction", new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                      new SelectListItem{ Text = "-Please Select Shift", Value = "0" },
                      new SelectListItem{ Text = "First Shift", Value = "1" },
                      new SelectListItem{ Text = "Second Shift", Value = "2" },
                      new SelectListItem{ Text = "Third Shift", Value = "3" }
                    }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "st", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "et", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServiceProviderID, "ServiceProviderID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ServiceProviderID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServiceProviderID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BranchID, "BranchID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("BranchID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BranchID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Your question does not appear to match your code. The above is simply a *display-only* list (standard MVC scaffolding `index` view). Can you show the editing page you refer to? (preferably the output HTML saved from the browser as this question is all about the client-side code).

Comment: [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: thanks for the replay, as you said it's a standard MVC scaffolding even for Create view, so the create page is per record not as table view, so I was thinking to place that button in the index page, where all the records are shown .. maybe it's not a good solution .. If you have any tips I can work on it thanks